# PySpark: append/merge PythonRDD to a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using the following code to create a clustering model, then classify each record to certain cluster:

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
rdd = spark_df.rdd.map(lambda data: Vectors.dense([float(c) for c in data]))
model = KMeans.train(rdd, 2, maxIterations=10,  initializationMode="random")

result = model.predict(red)
```

How do I append the predicted result back to the spark_df as an additional column? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `ml` in the first place?

Comment: I was unable to convert spark_df (data frame) to spark dataset. And if I just use data frame with ml, it won't work. Any suggestion on how to convert data frame to dataset? Thanks!

Comment: If I use ml: model = kmeans.fit(spark_df), I got errors: AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`features`' given input columns: [field_1, field_2, ... field10];"  So it seems to me that I can't use spark_df directly

Comment: @SandipanDey withcolumn only works for derived columns from existing columns. here it does not give expected result.

Comment: @Edamame were you able to figure out this issue? any help would be great ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel` is one of rare models that can be used directly inside PySpark transformation so you can simply `map` with `predict`:

```
rdd.map(lambda point: (model.predict(point), point))
```

In general case when it is not possible `zip` is the right tool for the job:

```
rdd.zip(model.predict(rdd))
```

Comment: zip gives out a tuple with the row and the predicted value.. how can we add it as a column "new_col" to the dataframe itself , so that we can write it back to db using saveastable().

Comment: @venkat This is `mllib` not `ml`. With `ml` models just use `transform` method.

Comment: i was talking about mllib not ml, how do i get data frame with additional  prediction column and write back to db?

Comment: @venkat `mllib` doesn't use `DataFrames`. If you want `DataFrame` as n output you have to follow standard steps to convert your `RDD`. `ml` provides this out-of-the-box.